# How to plot lat/long pairs over map in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I'm having a problem plotting points from a geoJSON file over a map using D3.js. The map is rendering fine, but the points are not showing up. I'm not receiving any error messages at this time.

I'm following along with [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mapsam/6090056) but using my own geoJSON file to plot the data.

This is what I have:

```
    var width = 960,
        height = 500;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var g = svg.append("g");

    var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
        .scale(1000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection);

    d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.json, 'states.json') // Load US States
        .defer(d3.json, 'trump_geoJson.json') // Load tweet lat/long data 
        .await(makeMyMap); // Run 'ready' when JSONs are loaded

    function makeMyMap(error,states,tweets) {
        svg.append('path')
            .datum(topojson.feature(states, states.objects.usStates))
            .attr('d', path)
            .attr('class', 'states');
        svg.selectAll('.tweets')
            .data(tweets.features)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('d',path)
            .attr('class', 'tweets');
    }
```

I'm expecting about 600 points to be plotted, but getting none.

The json file trump_geoJson looks like:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 0,
        "properties": {
            "primary_geo": "Utah, USA",
            "tag": "#Bernie",
            "text": "text",
            "user_id": "id"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                39.32373809814453,
                -111.67823791503906
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 1,
        "properties": {
            "primary_geo": "New York, NY",
            "tag": "#Bernie",
            "text": "text",
            "user_id": "id"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                40.71455001831055,
                -74.00714111328125
            ]
        }
    },... ]
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some path attributes (mainly `.attr("d",...)`) to the paths you are appending for each data item (each point), currently you are adding a path, but not specifying where it should go or how it should be drawn (or how the data should be projected). If you include your data structure, or an example of your data, it will be easier to help provide a solution that does this; however, if your items are valid geojson objects, then you should be able to use `.attr("d",path)`.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewReid, I changed the code as advised and added an example of the geojson. That didn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your geojson uses the wrong coordinate convention. You have:

```
"coordinates": [ latitude, longitude ]
```

But, you must use:

```
"coordinates": [ longitude, latitude ]
```

From the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-1.3):

> Point coordinates are in x, y order (easting, northing for projected
> coordinates, longitude, and latitude for geographic coordinates)

*It is funny that the spec considers eastings and northings for projected coordinates given the spec also states geojson must use unprojected (lat/long) coordinates using the WGS84 datum*

Here's a demo of the first two items in your geojson feature collection:

```js
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-111.6782379150,39.32373809814]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-74.00714111328,40.71455001831]
        }
    }]};
    

var width = 500,
height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .scale(600)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
   .projection(projection);

d3.json("https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1/world/110m.json", function(error, world) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(world)))
    .attr("fill","none")
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width",1);
    
  svg.selectAll('.tweets')
   .data(data.features)
   .enter()
   .append('path')
   .attr('d',path)
   .attr('class', 'tweets');
    
   
});
```

```css
  .tweets {
      fill: red;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v2.min.js"></script>
```